# Reduce multiclass classification targets to binary classification targets in scikit-learn

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification, binary

I would like to reduce multiclass classification targets to binary classification targets. Ideally, this mapping would happen within scikit-learn so the same transformation applies during both training and prediction.

I looked at [transforming the prediction target (y)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html) documentation but did not see something that would work. Ideally, it would be a classifier version of [TransformedTargetRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html).

Something like this mapping:

```py
targets_multi  = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}
targets_binary = {0: {'A', 'B'},
                  1: {'C', 'D'}}
```

Comment: Do those two dictionaries exactly represent what you want to do? Why not just create a new dictionary with two new keys and so on?

Comment: I would like the functionality in native scikit-learn code so I get the benefits of the ecosystem, such as use in pipelines.

Comment: Still a bit unclear. You can create your own transformers to work in a pipeline, in your case convert `targets_multi` from a set into a list and then create your new dictionary `targets_binary`

Answer (score 1):

Of the [three stated purposes](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#pipeline-chaining-estimators) of pipelines, you'd get the "convenience and encapsulation" one, but not the others:

- Joint parameter selection: you don't have any parameters for this transformation.
- Safety (from data leak): your transformation is context-specific, so there is no data leakage in applying it to the entire dataset up front.

This feels like something that is the definition of the targets, and is best considered a part of the data retrieval.

---

scikit-learn expects `transform` methods to have input just `X` and not `y`.  For the most part, you can work around that by overriding `fit_transform` from `TransformerMixin`.  However, nothing downstream will expect to get two return values (transformed `X` and `y`), so this won't work.

You can make a little more headway with the `imbalanced-learn` package, which provides its own `Pipeline` with more flexible transformation syntax.  The purpose there is to implement resamplers, and that throws a major issue: resamplers do not apply at prediction time.